# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to data type bit in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2005

Here i try to convert a bit value to varchar , i try this query in MS sql server

```
CASE WHEN cast(ISNULL(O.isTerminated,0)as varchar) = 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE '' END AS   isTerminated.
```

Is giving error "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Yes' to data type bit."

what will be the solution for this.

Comment: There's nothing in this particular piece of code that can cause the said error. I think you should show the query that this snippet is a part of.

Comment: What datatype is the "isTerminated" column?

Comment: Datatype of isTerminated coloumn is 'bit'

Comment: Do you use the `isTerminated` column in the where clause? Like this `isTerminated = 'Yes'`? In the where clause you are referencing the table column that is a `bit` not the column alias.

Answer (score 2):

The error is not caused by the statement you are showing but by what you do with your `isTerminated` alias afterwards.

**Your statement as is doesn't throw any errors.**

```
DECLARE @isTerminated BIT = 1
SELECT CASE WHEN CAST(ISNULL(@isTerminated, 0) AS VARCHAR) = 1 
            THEN 'yes' 
            ELSE  '' 
       END AS isTerminated
```

**But treating the aliased `isTerminated` as a `bit` does.**

```
DECLARE @isTerminated BIT = 1
SELECT  *
FROM    (SELECT CASE WHEN CAST(ISNULL(@isTerminated, 0) AS VARCHAR) = 1 
                     THEN 'yes' 
                     ELSE '' 
                END AS isTerminated) t
WHERE   isTerminated = 1 -- isTerminated is a VARCHAR at this point
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you casting the `bit` to a `varchar`. Can you just do this:

```
CASE WHEN ISNULL(O.isTerminated,0) = 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE '' END AS isTerminated
```

**EDIT**

When trying this example.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(isTerminated BIT)
INSERT INTO @T
VALUES(1),(NULL),(0)

SELECT
    CASE WHEN ISNULL(O.isTerminated,0) = 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE '' END AS isTerminated
FROM
    @T AS O
```

With your case statement. I don't revise a error. Are you missing out any details?

Comment: I have tried this also before , the same error comes thats why i use cast.Wheter we can solve this issue, using convert..?

Comment: Actually its a part of my stored procedure,whether  i want to post my stored procedure here...?